# Do alkenes have priority over alkynes in R/S naming?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, molecular-structure

I am studying for an upcoming exam and I came upon a confusing question for the drawing of the molecule (3⁠*R*)-hex-1-en-5-yn-3-ol.

[image: (3R)-hex-1-en-5-yn-3-ol]

Why is the stereocenter (3-carbon) R? Shouldn't it be S? After looking at it, I see that the priority is OH > alkyne > alkene. I'm really confused.

Comment: The carbon 3 is not directly connected to alkyne. It I'd connected to CH2 group which is connected to alkyne. Alkene(CH=CH2) has higher priority than CH2 group

Comment: The priority goes for this molecule as: i) $\ce{OH}$; ii) $\ce{C,C,H}$; iii) $\ce{C,H,H}$ and therefore, (*R*)- is the correct assignment.

Comment: **Please don’t write answers in comments!** It bypasses our quality measures by not having voting (both up and down) available on comments. Comments are for clarifying and improving the question; please don’t use them for other purposes.